# Are quote identifications on-topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

In particular, is the below question on-topic?

> The quote "Always go too far, because that's where you'll find the truth" has been attributed to [Albert Camus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Camus) in various places on the internet. For example, this one:
>
> [image: a picture of Camus alongside a black area with "Always go too far, because that's where you'll find the truth. - Albert Camus - AZ Quotes" written]
>
> However user @verbose in Literature SE has an answer in depth explaining [why it can't be from Camus](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/16681/1015). I wonder then who would likely to say this quote?

Comment: Done: [Who said “Always go too far, because that's where you'll find the truth”?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/78843/19487)

Answer (score 2):

### Answer

I would say that such a question should be allowed because it is on its face a question about the history of philosophy. What better place to ask about what Camus or Husserl said than Philosophy Stack Exchange? But I believe in the broader vision of philosophy and am at odds with other contributors who don't favor the use of editorial discretion. If you find otherwise, you might avoid downvotes/closure by simply asking what does the quotation means with adequate context.